# Spreadsheetgear - Add background color via conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vb.net, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to add a salmon background color when a cell's value exceeds a certain threshold. Here's my code:

```
Dim condition As IFormatCondition = thisRow(0, 6).FormatConditions.Add(FormatConditionType.CellValue, FormatConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, 0.035, Nothing)
condition.Interior.Color = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(230, 184, 183)
```

The condition is created correctly but for whatever reason, instead of setting the background color to salmon, it uses rgb(192, 192, 192).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your salmon has spoiled.

Comment: @djv - https://gph.is/15xZ8qn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. You are using SpreadsheetGear 2012 (V7) or earlier.  These older versions of SpreadsheetGear have limited support for Conditional Formatting (CF)--one of which was limited support for 24-bit colors.  When you specify an arbitrary 24-bit color for a CF that wasn't located in the workbook's 56-color palette (IWorkbook.[Colors](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017%7ESpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook%7EColors.html)), SpreadsheetGear will map the provided color to the closest match within the palette.

   SpreadsheetGear 2017 / V8 vastly improved support for Conditional Formatting, including the ability to use arbitrary 24-bit RGB colors, so upgrading could fix this issue.
2. You are saving to the older Excel 97-2003 (*.xls) file format.  Even if you are using SpreadsheetGear 2017+, if you save to this older file format, the CF will lose the 24-bit color and, again, map to the closest color found in the workbook's 56-color palette.  In this case it would be best to save to an Open XML (*.xlsx or *.xlsm) file format, which does have full 24-bit color support.

Comment: Yep, I'm using the old 2012 version. I updated the color line to `condition.Interior.Color = Colors.LightSalmon` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!